# How to use else statement to check string entry

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

I have added an array containing string values in my programme where I want to add an else statement so that if someone enters a value that is not contained in the array, in would print out a message `invalid entry`.

I have written this in the programme but if a correct value is entered the invalid entry still appears when I run the code.

Enter your name
barry
you are verified you may use the lift

Invalid entry

Invalid entry

Invalid entry

This is what I get

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username

{
public static void main (String[]args)
{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    // array containing usernames 
    String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; // elements in array


    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name1 = kb.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if(name[i].equals(name1)) {
        System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
        }else{System.out.println ("Invalid entry");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping over the array, you could just convert the array to a list in use `contains`:

```
System.out.println("Enter your name");
String name1 = kb.nextLine();
if (Arrays.asList(name).contains(name1)) { 
    System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
} else {
    System.out.println ("Invalid entry");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean variable and keep there information if user has been found.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    // array containing usernames
    String[] name = { "barry", "matty", "olly", "joey" }; // elements in
                                                            // array

    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name1 = kb.nextLine();
    boolean b = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if (name[i].equals(name1)) {
            System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (b) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of how you iterate and compare. You compare the value entered to all the names with a for loop. Barry doesn't equal "matty", "olly" or "joey", but your for loop still compares all of them.

Your problem is that if outputs on all comparisons.

I would recommend setting a boolean before the loop, and if it finds a match - set that boolean to `true`.
Then when the loop has ended, simply check if the boolean is true or false, and output the desired code.

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username

{
   public static void main (String[]args)
   {

Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
// array containing usernames 
String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; // elements in array


System.out.println("Enter your name");
String name1 = kb.nextLine();

Boolean foundMatch = false;

for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if(name[i].equals(name1)) 
        foundMatch = true;
}
if(foundMatch)
   System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
else
    System.out.println ("Invalid entry")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `boolean` value to save your status.

```
boolean contais = false;
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if(name[i].equals(name1)) {
        contais = true;
        break;// to stop looping
    }else{contais = false;}
}

if(contais) {
    System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
else {
    System.out.println ("Invalid entry");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
    if(name[i].equals(name1))
```

Try This :

```
       if(name[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name1))
```